# How to proper handle governor limits inside a platform event handler?

Tags: platform-event, architecture

In a platform event trigger handler that needs to insert a list of SObjects that comes from the event payload. We can do a wrapper `try catch` to protect of all errors and log in a custom object, we can also insert partially and with the `Database.SaveResult` log all the errors.

But in a situation where you have `Database.insert(sobjectList, false);` can result in an uncatchable governor limit. What is best practice or proper way on this scenarios?

Or the only way is to use event monitoring filtered with `ApexUnexpectedException` and if these situations happens we need to fine tune the batch size for the handler.

Thank you

Comment: An option is to launch a queueable from the trigger subscriber that itself implements finalizer and have it handle failure cases (the finalizer can run even for governor limit issues).

Comment: BTW, I would avoid putting important data in a platform event since these are not guaranteed to be delivered and could be lost.

Comment: my strategy has been to insert the PE to a custom object then fire an async txn against that custom object (this is what Phil W suggests I believe). Thus, the trigger handler is merely stashing the PEs in an operation that won't fail. The async can be coded to be recoverable

Comment: Thanks Phil, I will investigate that option with queueable.
Thanks cropredy, yes I already saw this kind of implementation. The issue I find with  that is depending on the volume can be very hard to maintain due to Storage issue. Like 25M of events every day. And having to build a batch to delete can create overhead. But that for lower volumes is definitely a solid option